# When something is deleted in a database how do you change the other records so that the id of the records change

Tags: mysql, css, database, record

How would I ensure that when something is deleted in a database the id of the records are changed so I get a continuous, consecutive collection of ids, e.g. I have a record with ID 1 and another record with ID 2 and another with ID 3, when 2 is deleted, how can I ensure that the ID of the record '3' will now be '2'.

Comment: If `id` is a primary key you shouldnt.

Comment: Why would you want this?  its a key, sequence, order, skipping numbers, none of that should matter...

Comment: It could be done, but it would be most unwise. Might be better to say why you need/want to do this

Comment: why not have queries return a rownum value or something similar since your using mysql  like... `SET @rownum:=0; SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS rownum, * FROM tab;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You normally don't, in particular if this is a primary key and even more so if it is used as a foreign key (then you will need to change it *everywhere* it is referenced).

Having "holes" in your table is not an operational issue at all.

Answer (score 0):

Let `$deleted_id` be the ID of the record you deleted.

```
UPDATE yourtable SET id = id - 1 WHERE id > $deleted_id
```

But please be aware that you also have to update all references to your IDs, if any exist.

Answer (score 0):

Your not supposed to do this with Primary Keys as it would effect other records in tables that are joined.

Maybe if you have a specific reason for doing this then we can help?

Comment: well, i want to store an img src in a field, then i want to display three images next to each other, to do this i am querying the table to call the img src of a variable (1) another variable of (2) and another variable of (3) when the 'next' button is clicked the query gets the img src of all the variables ihncremented by one. Is this fine?

Comment: We'd have to see some code your using, but there is always another way to do things.
You definately dont want to be updating your records like you suggest.